# Apex List Of Values definition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

[image: APEX LOV]

Is there a way to query the table that :P5_NS_ID poits to? Get an error when doing this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Building an APEX List of Values with Cascading References

[@Frank Schmitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/610979/frank-schmitt) was close in his solution with his query suggestion:

```
select "name" from (
  select * from dns_servers where id = :P5_NS_ID)
where "type" = :P5_REC_TYPE_ID
```

To get over the errors you encountered however requires a few reminders of the rules behind the type of Oracle APEX element you are trying to create, a `LIST OF VALUES QUERY`.  Here's a screenshot of the Examples for query based LOVs posted in the Apex developer area:

[image: Oracle APEX List of Values Query Setup]

Note that there needs to be TWO columns in the output of your query.  The value in position 1 is the `DISPLAY VALUE` (what is shown in the selection dialogue that uses it.) And `RETURN VALUE` (what is actually returned as the input value to the page item that shows the options from the query.

You may also be having some difficulty with implementing the logic of cascading input parameters.  Below is an example of how to figure it out.

### Setting up the Example Schema, HR-EMP

Here are the table structures used in my example:

**DEPT**

```
CREATE TABLE  "DEPT" 
   (    "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0), 
        "DNAME" VARCHAR2(14), 
        "LOC" VARCHAR2(13), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("DEPTNO") ENABLE
   )
/
```

**EMP**

```
CREATE TABLE  "EMP" 
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10), 
        "JOB" VARCHAR2(9), 
        "MGR" NUMBER(4,0), 
        "HIREDATE" DATE, 
        "SAL" NUMBER(7,2), 
        "COMM" NUMBER(7,2), 
        "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0), 
         PRIMARY KEY ("EMPNO") ENABLE
   )
/

ALTER TABLE  "EMP" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("MGR")
    REFERENCES  "EMP" ("EMPNO") ENABLE
/
ALTER TABLE  "EMP" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("DEPTNO")
    REFERENCES  "DEPT" ("DEPTNO") ENABLE
/
```

**This example will use three LOV queries:**

1. The first LOV Query is in page item: `P3_FIRST_CHOICE` is *independent* of any value.  It offers the user a choice of `DEPARTMENT` values.

   ```
   SELECT DNAME || ', ' || LOC as d, DEPTNO as r
     FROM DEPT
   ```
2. The second LOV Query is in page item: `P3_SECOND_CHOICE` and relies on the input of the selection for `P3_FIRST_CHOICE`.

   ```
   SELECT distinct JOB d, JOB r
     FROM emp
    WHERE emp.deptno = :P3_FIRST_CHOICE
   ```

   This makes `P3_SECOND_CHOICE` the first `CASCADING PARAMETER` value, so the cascading LOV Parent Item is:  `P3_FIRST_CHOICE`.  For a given department the user may select a specific `JOB`.

   *Notice that even if the return value is the same as the display, TWO columns are required in an LOV query output.*
3. The third LOV Query is in page item: `P3_THIRD_CHOICE` and relies on the input of the selections for:  `P3_FIRST_CHOICE` and `P3_SECOND_CHOICE`.

   ```
   SELECT ENAME d, EMPNO r
     FROM emp
    WHERE DEPTNO = :P3_FIRST_CHOICE
      AND JOB = :P3_SECOND_CHOICE
   ```

   `P3_THIRD_CHOICE` has a `CASCADING PARAMETER` dependency and offers a selection of employee names who have records that match the selected `DEPARTMENT` and `JOB` values from the first two form selection items.
4. There is an optional fourth query which populates a report on the `EMPLOYEE` that is selected from the third LOV selection list.

Your APEX form design may look something like this:

[image: Employee Query Form Design]

### How to Get New Parameters From Cascading Form Input Items

This is the example query form:

[image: APEX Cascading LOV Entry Form Example]

**Entry Selection for the FIRST CHOICE (Department):**

[image: APEX Cascading LOV Department Selection Choice]

**Entry Selection for the SECOND CHOICE (Job):**

[image: APEX Cascading LOV Job Selection Choice]

**Entry Selection for the THIRD CHOICE (Employee):**

[image: APEX Cascading LOV Employee Selection Choice]

**Final Output:  Individual Query by Selected Employee**

[image: APEX Employee Report from Cascading LOV Parameters]

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the bit about the two columns.  I had inferred that to be the case but didn't find any documentation stating as such.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an APEX expert, but this query looks broken - you're returning a single column called `server_name` from your inner query, and you're trying to reference two columns called `"name"` and `"type"` in your outer query.

If your table `dns_servers` indeed contains columns called `"name"` and `"id"`, I'd suggest returning all columns from the inner query:

```
  select "name" from (
    select * from dns_servers where id = :P5_NS_ID)
  where "type" = :P5_REC_TYPE_ID
```